# RestTemplate how to convert a string to object that come as a string?

Tags: java, json, resttemplate

I consume a web service that return one of its fields as a `String`, but this field is a actually a object, such as below:

```
{
    "message": "OK",
    "code": 1,
    "supplierPayload": "{\"field01\":\"value01\",\"field02\":\"field02\"}"
}
```

Is it possible anyway to parse the supplierPayload json field returned as a `String` into the `SupplierPayload` object I need in the RestTemplate call?

I would have:

```
this.restTemplate.getForEntity(url, MyObject.class);
```

And MyObject would be

```
public class MyObject {

    private String message;
    private int code;
    private SupplierPayload supplierPayload;

    // gets and sets
}
```

instead of

```
public class MyObject {

    private String message;
    private int code;
    private String supplierPayload;

    // gets and sets
}
```

This will prevent me to have an instance of ObjectMapper Spring bean anywhere I need to use this field and convert it manually handling the nest checked exceptions that ObjectMapper brings in its methods.

Comment: Prefer changing the service to return a json object. Failing that, call `Map<String, Object> supplierPayloadMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(myObject.getSupplierPayload(), HashMap.class)`.

Comment: I am not the developer of the other web service. The solution you provided is actually what I am trying to avoid, write the ObjectMapper conversion to MyObject in various places of my code.

Comment: You could create a custom Jackson annotation that processes the string into an object.

Comment: Could you, please, provide an example answer? Thanks for your comment.